# Create table from excel file in an email with MS Flow and Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, excel-online

I'm trying to get the data from the attachment of an email which is an Excel file, I want to get the data in order to create a table so SharePoint can handle the data, so far this is what I have:
[image]

But it fails, the error is this even when in the Create File section the output of the ItemId is 1522, when I check the Get file metadata input the file identifier is 1522. Can you point me in the right direction?

> The file /sites/example/1522 does not exist.
> clientRequestId: xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx
> serviceRequestId: xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the flow as shown below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Result for your reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can break this task into two simple Flows:

1. Save email attachment to a document library.
2. Read Excel file from the document library and create new SharePoint list items

**1) Save my email attachments to a SharePoint document library**

Create a new Power Automate flow using a template called "**Save email attachment to a document library.**" Configure it according to your needs. For example, you can only monitor emails by specific subject, etc. You should also select a document library that will store your Excel files.

[image]

**2. Read Excel file from the document library and create new SharePoint list items**

Now that you have Excel files automatically deposited to your document library, you can create a new Flow. This flow will be triggered on "file created".

- Use **When a file is created** trigger
- Add **Get tables** action
- Add **List rows present in a table** action
- Add **Create Item** action

[image]

This should be enough to get the entire process working.

Comment: I think I didn´t explain myself correctly, the excel file contains data, from that data I want to create a table in the same excel file as if you do Insert>Table in Excel.